# Writing Unit Tests to Queue triggered Azure webjob

Tags: azure, unit-testing, azure-webjobs

Is there a way to add unit tests to Azure webjobs ? I see lot of queries and articles for Azure functions but none for webjobs.
Anything in that direction would be extremely helpful
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can this help: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/09/06/make-your-azure-webjobs-unit-testable-again/ ?

Comment: Specifically, how are you triggering the webjob you want to test?

Comment: @PeterBons thanks. But we dont use JobHostConfiguration anymore in webjobs. Latest version we use HostBuilder and the article seems to be specifically for JobHost

Comment: @RobReagan its triggered using storage queuetrigger